# Call a function whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following script:

```
(function () {
    var Module = (function () {
        var fctToCall = function () {
            alert('Foo');
        };
        return {
            fctToCall: fctToCall
        };
    })();
    var Module2 = (function () {
        var init = function () {
            var str = 'fctToCall';
            Module.str(); // here
        };
        return {
            init: init
        };
    })();
})();
```

So I want to call this `fctToCall` method by its name - how can I do that? So far I know 3 methods:

- by attaching the function to the window object, but then it wouldn't be local and in closure, and I wouldn't have the access to other local variables
- eval, the best options as far as I see it, but it's still eval, so I don't wanna use it
- this, but it's another architecture, I don't wanna change it

How can I solve this?

Comment: Close-voters: This question is clear enough.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To call function use

```
Module[str]();
```

As `Module` is an object, you can access the dynamic properties and methods of it by using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

```js
(function() {
  var Module = (function() {
    var fctToCall = function() {
      console.log('Foo');
    };
    return {
      fctToCall: fctToCall
    };
  })();
  var Module2 = (function() {
    var init = function() {
      var str = 'fctToCall';
      
      // Call as
      Module[str]();
    };
    return {
      init: init
    };
  })();

  Module2.init();
})();
```

Comment: `Module` is not a function. It's an object. Specifically: `{ fctToCall: fctToCall }`

Comment: Thank you @Cerbrus. my bad.

Comment: “Subscript notation”? It’s usually called the bracket notation.

Answer (score 6):

Replace:

```
var init = function () {
    var str = 'fctToCall';
    Module.str(); // here
};
```

With:

```
var init = function () {
    var str = 'fctToCall';
    Module[str](); // here
};
```

Here, `str` is used as key to access the `fctToCall` function on `Module`.

Then you can call `Module2.init()`, in your [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```js
(function() {
  var Module = (function() {
    var fctToCall = function() {
      document.write('Foo'); // (alert is broken in snippets)
    };
    return {
      fctToCall: fctToCall
    };
  })();
  var Module2 = (function() {
    var init = function() {
      var str = 'fctToCall';
      Module[str](); // Access & call `fctToCall`.
    };
    return {
      init: init
    };
  })();
  Module2.init(); // Call `init`.
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since everything in JS is object you can use the object notation.

```
Module[str]();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just invoke the function like this:

```
Module[str]();
```