# How to call an on page function with playwright?

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer, playwright

I'm using playwright to scrape some data from a page.  I need to call a page function in order to change the browser's state to collect additional info.

What's the syntax for getting a function name from a data attribute and then calling that function on the page?

I keep getting the error :`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: page.evaluate: Evaluation failed: TypeError: cb is not a function`

Here's what I have so far:

```
const { chromium} = require("playwright");

(async()=>{

    this.browser = await chromium.launch({
            headless: true,
        });
        this.context = await this.browser.newContext();
        this.page = await this.context.newPage();
        this.page.goto('http://fakeExample.org')
    const callbackHandle = await this.page.$('[data-callback]');
    const cbName = await callbackHandle.evaluate(element=>element.getAttribute('data-callback')); //returns actual page function name 'myPageFunction'

    this.page.evaluate((cb) => {
        cb() //should call myPageFunction() on the page
    }, cbName)


})()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it comes down to either `window[cb]()` or `eval(cb)` since you're passing in a string with the function name.

Some reading on this topic:

- [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)
- [Call a JavaScript function name using a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496961/call-a-javascript-function-name-using-a-string)
- [Call a function whose name is stored in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869456/call-a-function-whose-name-is-stored-in-a-variable)